# Identify this film about a Boy, girl and Girl's Dog

Tags: comedy, identify-this-movie

I remember watching a movie where a mature boy has a crush on a girl and tries to impress her. But the problem is that the girl has a dog (most probably a female dog) which creates problems that prevent them from getting together.

In one scene the couple is going to kiss but the dog licks the girl's face. The girl still tries to kiss the boy but the boy can't because he has seen the dog drinking toilet water from pot earlier before licking the girl's face (the girl doesn't notice this).

Similarly, in another scene the boy is trying to have intercourse with the girl, but the Dog got excited and licked the boy between his legs.

It's most probably an American comedy film, most likely no older than 2000, but I'm not sure about the time period. I watched it on an Indian TV channel more then 4 years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie you're looking for is 2007 release, [Heavy Petting](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0491211/) featuring Malin Akerman and Brendan Hines.

The wiki synopsis has this:

> In present day New York City, Charlie (Brendan Hines) meets the girl
>   of his dreams, Daphne (Malin Åkerman), but he never expected he'd have
>   to battle past her pet dog "Babydoll" to woo her. Just when it seems
>   he can't beat the beast and all is lost, something unexpected happens:
>   Charlie begins to fall in love with the dog himself, realizing he
>   never really needed a girlfriend in the first place. Now, in order to
>   keep hanging out with "man's best friend", Charlie must scramble to
>   keep the relationship with Daphne going at all costs - or risk losing
>   them both.

The scene you referred to, about the dog drinking toilet water and then kissing the girl is there on YouTube [trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0z3oGtLGlNo)